# kitchen verify hangs on centOS, but not Debian

Tags: chef

`.kitchen.yml`

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: debian-9
  - name: centos-7

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[foo::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    attributes: 
      foo: 
        sshd: 
          port: 22
```

cmd: `$ kitchen verify`

debian-9 finishes just fine, no problems.
centos-7 just hangs and hangs.

I don't believe it's the tests. They are standard inspec control checks. If I comment out the tests, the same thing happens.

Any idea what could be happening here?

`format: documentation` output:

```
Finished in 0.75833 seconds (files took 0.90276 seconds to load)
30 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending

       Finished verifying <default-debian-9> (0m1.91s).
-----> Verifying <default-centos-7>...
```

Nada. The "1 pending" is just a check that has been ignored due to OS detection.

This was working earlier today and stopped working out of the blue. I tried destroying the vagrant box.

Comment: I left it to run all night and it eventually finished. That won't work for CI.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem show up.  I think it's related to SSH.  I was writing a custom sshd_config.  Vagrant login's were slow after the first converge and verify was taking forever.  Removing the sshd_config stuff from my cookbook fixed the verify and slow logins.

Maybe it's not very helpful, but it's a place to start looking, anyway.  Short term, I hacked it together:

```
unless ENV['TEST_KITCHEN']
  cookbook_file '/etc/ssh/sshd_config' do
    source 'sshd_config'
    mode '0644'
    notifies :restart, 'service[sshd]', :delayed
  end
end
```

Jye

Comment: Yes that does seem to be the problem. The other problem is that I _do_ want to test the SSH stuff. I wonder if there's any way to speed it up? Hm.

Comment: When I get a moment, I'm going to start commenting my sshd_config until I find what causes it to hang.